# LibGdx Scalling sprites on Android

Tags: android, libgdx, sprites, scale

I have a sprite that is a few buttons but need them in the center of the screen for all android devices. I tried setting it's location to the center of the screen by dividing the orthogonal camera by 2, but it doesn't help. Any simple way to fix this?

Comment: Your title asks for scaling, your question asks for centralization. What are you really asking here? What do you want to fix?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw the sprite in the exact center, you have to take the sprite's height and width into account. Assuming your viewport's width and height are set equal to the device's width and height. You can set the sprite's position this way

```
sprite.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - sprite.getWidth())/2 ,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - sprite.getheight())/2 );
```

or even:

```
batch.draw(texture, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - texture.getWidth())/2 ,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - texture.getheight())/2);
```